# Creating SQL INSERT statement out of XML file data

Tags: sql, xml, xslt

I want to generate an SQL INSERT statement from data encoded in XML files, using an XSLT.

My XML files include, for example, the following tags (describing a tombstone):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.stoa.org/epidoc/schema/latest/tei-epidoc.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:lang="en">
    <teiHeader>
        <fileDesc>
            <titleStmt>
                <title>Funerary inscription for Marcellus, a smith</title>
            </titleStmt>
            <publicationStmt>
                <authority>I.Sicily</authority>
                <idno type="TM">491539</idno>
            </publicationStmt>
            <sourceDesc>
                <msDesc>
                    <msIdentifier>
                        <country>Italy</country>
                        <region>Sicily</region>
                        <settlement>Catania</settlement>
                        <repository role="museum" ref="http://sicily.classics.ox.ac.uk/museum/018"
                            >Museo Civico di Catania </repository>
                        <idno type="inventory">390</idno>
                        <altIdentifier>
                            <settlement/>
                            <repository/>
                            <idno type="old"/>
                        </altIdentifier>
                    </msIdentifier>
                    <msContents>
                        <textLang mainLang="la">Latin </textLang>
                    </msContents>
                    <physDesc>
                        <objectDesc>
                            <supportDesc>
                                <support>
                                    <material n="marble"
                                        ref="http://www.eagle-network.eu/voc/material/lod/48.html"
                                        >marble </material>
                                    <objectType n="tabula"
                                        ref="http://www.eagle-network.eu/voc/objtyp/lod/257">tablet </objectType>
                                    <dimensions>
                                        <height unit="cm">29</height>
                                        <width unit="cm">33.5</width>
                                        <depth unit="cm">2.1</depth>
                                    </dimensions>
                                </support>
                            </supportDesc>
                        </objectDesc>
                    </physDesc>
                </msDesc>
            </sourceDesc>
        </fileDesc>
    </teiHeader>
<!-- lots more content that I cut away here -->
</TEI>
```

I would like to extract information from this and insert it into an SQL table.

My desired output would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblObjects
(ObjectID, Title, TMid, Material, ObjectType, Height)
VALUES
('Funerary inscription for Marcellus, a smith', 491539, 'marble', 'tabula', 29);
```

My original - now solved - problem was this:

> I tried setting the output method to text after some examples I found
>   online, but this is giving me the error message "Non-whitespace
>   characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo'
>   and 'xs:documentation'."

I changed the file format to xsl, now it's no longer complaining about the non-whitespace characters. I can now put text into the final output. The following (inspired by your answers) is the current state of my XSLT, for now I want to try to just insert the value of the title, the position of which is "TEI/teiHeader/fileDesc/titleStmt/title":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text"
        encoding="UTF-8" 
        omit-xml-declaration="yes"
        indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>INSERT INTO tblObjects</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>(ObjectID, Title, TMid, Material, ObjectType, Height) VALUES (</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root"/>    
        <xsl:text>);</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:value-of select="TEI/teiHeader/fileDesc/titleStmt/title"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives me the following output:

```
INSERT INTO tblObjects(ObjectID, Title, TMid, Material, ObjectType, Height) VALUES ();
```

Yet, as you can see, it does not insert the value of the title. I am not sure why that's not working (only trying the title for now).

Comment: Tag your dbms, xml tools are product specific.

Comment: Please show the root tag of XML as default namespaces may exist and is needed for XSLT.

Comment: The error message seems to suggest that somewhere along the line, a file is being treated as a schema document. You haven't given any clues as to why that should happen, there is no mention of schemas in your question, only in the error message.

Comment: Thank you, I found that I had accidentally saved the file as .xsd rather than .xsl, which I think was responsible for the error I got.

Comment: You see! You have a default namespace in root node. Also, does *teiHeader* repeat with other same nodes but different values? Usually for XML questions, we need the root node and enough sample to understand the XML pattern. Essentially is there only one set or more than one set of values to be used in SQL?

Comment: So, in one file, there will be only information about one stone, i.e. only one height, only one material. But, this may contain more than one language (the text on one stone may be in several languages), and usually more than one person (usually at least two people will be mentioned in the text on the stone, and encoded in the file. I will want to extract values for my SQL from multiple files, and when there's e.g. more than on person, I'll need several instances with the same tag from the same file. Hope this answers your question, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply walk down the tree with templates and concatenate values with needed quotes and commas for SQL query's `VALUES` clause. Due to the many nested structure of XML, `ancestor::*` and `descendant::*` paths are used for specific node value extraction.

Note: This solution works for XML files for one *teiHeader*. You will need to tailor this solution or run other XSLT scripts for other types.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:doc="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/doc:TEI">
      <xsl:text>INSERT INTO tblObjects</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>(ObjectID, Title, TMid, Material, ObjectType, Height)&#xa;VALUES&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:teiHeader/doc:fileDesc/doc:sourceDesc/doc:msDesc/doc:physDesc"/>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="doc:physDesc">
        <xsl:variable name="quote">&apos;</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('(', 
                                     $quote, ancestor::doc:fileDesc/doc:titleStmt/doc:title, $quote, ', ', 
                                     ancestor::doc:fileDesc/doc:publicationStmt/doc:idno[@type='TM'], ', ',
                                     $quote, normalize-space(descendant::doc:material), $quote, ', ',
                                     $quote, normalize-space(descendant::doc:objectType), $quote, ', ',
                                     descendant::doc:dimensions/doc:height,
                                     ')' 
                                    )"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh3K/2)

Comment: Thank you, Parfait. I edited the original code up in the post. Now the text is working and appearing in the output. I am now trying to insert the values from the XML file into the output, but that is not currently working.

Comment: Did you see my solution with posted demo? You need to adjust to actual XML. Plus as I commented above, we need actual XML sample. No where do I see these tags: `TEI/teiHeader/fileDesc/titleStmt/`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I had not seen the demo, just the code you had posted. Well, in the guidelines it said I shouldn't post a whole file, so I tried to cut it to the absolute minimum, and in fact the whole file has more than 300 lines, but I see now why that didn't work and I will add an abbreviated version of my file in a couple of minutes.

Comment: I have added an extract from the actual file above so you can see the actual tags used in the file.

Comment: See updated script and demo that works only for your posted content. Per your general response that *tells* more than *shows*, I do not know how XML is structured for multiple person(s), multiple stone(s), multiple language(s), etc. You will need to tailor this XSLT to handle such specifications or run different XSLTs.

Comment: Yes, well, eventually I will have to write a *lot* more XSLTs for many more purposes, so I will need to understand how this works and be able to apply and adapt what you wrote. Thanks a lot, I'll try this and ask again if I run into problems or things I don't understand!